# How to effect the hovered div with jQuery via it's class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery function which, on the events `mouseover` and `mouseout` of the `<div>`s with the class `.myshp_list_product_image`, changes their `src` attribute.

The issue is that when I hover one of them, it also changes the others.
How can I make it only change the one being hovered?

Here's the code of the function:

```
$(function() {
  $('.myshp_list_product_image').mouseover(function() {
    $('.myshp_list_product_image').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.attr('src', $this.attr('src').replace('1s', '2s'));
    });
  });
  $('.myshp_list_product_image').mouseout(function() {
    $('.myshp_list_product_image').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.attr('src', $this.attr('src').replace('2s', '1s'));
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `.each()` here, get rid of it. You just need to target the current element i.e. `this`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.myshp_list_product_image').mouseover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('src', $this.attr('src').replace('1s', '2s'));
    });
    $('.myshp_list_product_image').mouseout(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('src', $this.attr('src').replace('2s', '1s'));
    });
});
```

I would recommend you to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event, A small [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/x6p87wqh/1/) for the difference between `mouseover` and `mouseenter`

Comment: Damn, i was writing dude :(

Answer (score 2):

Just target the currently hovered/hovered out element instead of iterating over all elements with same class.

Also you can use .hover instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout` and callback function of `.attr()` to minimize your code:

```
 $('.myshp_list_product_image').hover(
 function() {
    $(this).attr('src',function(i,oldattr){return oldattr.replace('1s', '2s')}); 
 }, function() {
    $(this).attr('src',function(i,oldattr){return oldattr.replace('2s', '1s')}); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use .hover() from jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.myshp_list_product_image').hover(function () { // mouse in
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('src', $this.attr('src').replace('1s', '2s'));

    }, function () { // mouse out
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('src', $this.attr('src').replace('2s', '1s'));

    });
});
```